# installation issue

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

i am unable to install MiKTex net installer. I could download setup file. When I run the setup file, installation directory is sought. When I select a directory and proceed it gives a warning "invalid Installation Source". How to install for windows 7, 32 bit system.

Comment: As it stands we are not likely to be able to help: MiKTeX  does install on many systems so this is not likely to be a general problem. Can you give more details: _exactly_ which version of the installer you have, screen shots of the issue, _etc._

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the error you're getting is the following

[image]

Note that the statement is that the directory *is not a valid* installation *source*.  What you are being prompted for here is the location of the downloaded MiKTeX files to use in the installation.  The default prompt is where the MiKTeX installer expects to find the folder, not necessarily where it is.

To use the MiKTeX Net Installer you must first download the appropriate files, on the first step of the installer select Download rather than Install to first obtain the files.

[image]

After selecting which package set to install and then the download source you are prompted to set a download destination, the default seems to use `C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\MiKTeX Download Files` but you can set this to be wherever you like.  This is the path which you need to enter when you return to do the actual installation.

[image]

After the download has completed you need to restart the installer and do the actual installation.

[image]

Now when you come to the screen to select the MiKTeX Distribution Directory, this should be the directory you selected earlier when downloading the MikTeX files and not where you want the program to be installed.  If this is not the directory you downloaded all the installation files to using the installer earlier, you will receive a "The directory ... is not a valid installation source" error.

[image]

The next screen is where you get to select the installation directory.

[image]