# pdflatex not found (windows)

Tags: pdftex, r, markdown

I am trying to exporty a pdf file from the R output using R markdown. I donwnloaded the MikTex, but when I tried to run the R markdown, it showed this error message:

```
pandoc.exe: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
```

When I typed sessionInfo() in R, I got this:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

It seems that R could not find the location of the downloaded latex:

```
Sys.which("pdflatex")
pdflatex 
  ""
```

Not sure if there is something wrong with downloading the MikTex, the location of the downloaded MikTex in my computer is:

```
"C:\Users\username\Desktop\MiKTeX Download Files"
```

And I reset the path in R, but still showed the same error:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\MikTeX Download Files\\miktex\\bin", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

I know the issue might be related to path setting, but not sure what exactly to do to solve this.
Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why didn't you install it in the default `C\Program Files`?

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but still could not work. After I finish downloading, there are many pieces of packages, and I could not find a folder called bin. strange...

Comment: The `bin` folder is in `C:Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`

Comment: Did you **install it**? https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue, it turns out that after I complete downloading, I should open the installer again and click on install MikTeX. I thought I just need to use that wizard once.
I found a detailed solution here:
[installation issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345142/installation-issue)